# Acceleration of log moving without slipping with/under a plank

Tags: acceleration, relative-motion

So I have this image:  [image]

I know how to solve the accompanying physics problem once I have determined the relative accelerations of the logs and the plank. According to my physics textbook, the cm of each log will move half the distance that the log will and thus the $a_{plank} = 2 a_{log}$. While this does seem to make sense and I can see it when I test it out with an eraser, I still can't seem to model it in my head. How does the cm of each log only move half the distance? If the log moves $2\pi R$ won't the log cm move $2R$? That clearly isn't half the distance. (There is friction between the logs and the plank and the logs and the ground).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point where the log touches the ground is the point where the log has zero velocity. If you now draw a small displacement, you see (from equal triangles) that if the center of the log moves $x$ the top moves $2x$ .

[image]